# Merge Rails objects, only keep present values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, merge

I have an array of objects that I want to merge into one:

```
[
  #<User firstname: 'John', middlename: '',   lastname: nil>
  #<User firstname: '',     middlename: '',   lastname: 'Doe'>
  #<User firstname: nil,    middlename: 'W.', lastname: nil>
]
```

This should become:

```
#<User firstname: 'John', middlename: 'W.', lastname: 'Doe'>
```

Is there an easy way for this or do I have to loop through all objects, look at the `.attributes` and build a new one?

***Update: My current state of code***

```
master = nil
my_array.each do |user|
  if !master
    master = user
  else
    user.attributes.each do |k, v|
      if v.present? && !master.send(k).present?
        master.send(:"#{k}=", v)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Well, it works, but the code doesn't look very clean...

Comment: What happens if you have multiple objects with an attribute set?

Comment: I updated my question what answers your question. It's not that important, since my objects always have only one attribute set.